# What does a "feminist son" mean?

Tags: meaning

Does anybody find a definition for it? I googled it but I couldn't find one.

"Earlier this year, Melinda Gates told Time Magazine that when raising a **feminist son**, she often thinks back to how her own parents taught her that she could do anything her brothers could."

Source: https://www.cnbc.com/2017/11/27/Michelle-Obama-warren-Buffett-and-bill-Gates-all-use-this-parenting-lesson-to-empower-their-kids.html

Comment: I'm guessing she's talking about her son. who happens to be a feminist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Melinda Gates' son's name is Rory who she thinks is a *feminist.* [Here is the main article](http://motto.time.com/4781066/melinda-gates-feminist-son-rory-gates/), and here is the main portion:

> *Rory, for his part, does. Across 18 years of conversations, sharp observations and everyday actions, he’s demonstrated **his belief that gender equality is something worth standing up for.** When we talk about these issues at the dinner table, he (and his friends!) have a lot to say.*
>
> [Feminist](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/feminist): *a person who believes in feminism, and tries to achieve change that helps women to get equal opportunities and treatment*

The paragraph is followed by an example where Rory supported gender equality and thus believed that women have equal rights on everything.

So, she's talking about raising Rory. And, while raising him, she thinks back that how her own parents were also supporting the gender equality.